# Show that T is a sufficient statistic

Tags: probability, statistics

Exponential family:

$f(x|\theta) = c(x)d(\theta)\exp[a(\theta)b(x)]$,

$T = \sum b(x_i)$.

I understand that a sufficient statistic is supposed to help factorize $f(x|\theta)$ into two different terms. I am not sure how to show that this can be factored into two terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of sufficiency is not quite what you said. Let's say you have a density $f(x|\theta)$ and that it factors like this:

$$f(x|\theta) = h(x) \cdot g(\theta, T(x))$$

In other words, the density factors into a part which involves **only** data (the function $h$), and into a part which depends on both the parameter $\theta$ and a function of the data $T(x)$ (the function $g$). In this case the function $T$ is said to be a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

The intuition behind this is that since $h(x)$ can be factored out from $g$, then it has no "interaction" with $\theta$ so any information contained in $h(x)$ will not affect your ability to estimate $\theta$. The only part of the data that matters is $T(x)$, since it interacts with $\theta$ through the function $g$.

In the exponential case, the factorization is $h(x) = c(x)$ and $g(\theta, T(x)) = d(\theta) \exp(a(\theta),b(x))$. Thus $g$ depends on $x$ solely through the function $b(x)$.